# Один пользователь для админок Joomla 2.5 и ModX Revo

Tags: php, joomla, modx

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы Человек авторизовавшись в админке Joomla, мог без авторизации войти в админку modX Revolution. Логины и пароли одинаковые. Но что-то никаких мыслей на этот счет нет. 
Может кто пробовал уже такое? И возможно ли это?

Comment: Возможно всё. Можно в сторону OAuth глянуть

Comment: Для данной задачи оказалось достаточно сделать две кнопки в jooml'е и modx'е. Две формы с логинами и паролями. При клике на каждую идет авторизация.